# Node 6.10 JavaScript Map vs Slice underlying differences

Tags: arrays, node.js

In Node, does Array#Slice iterate over each underlying item in the array similar to Array#Map or is there a separate more performant implementation? Looking through the node source at https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/9759573997a1bbd58fc0ba62e8aa1b4f607ec158/deps/v8/src/interpreter/constant-array-builder.cc (Which I *believe* is the slice implementation although I could be wrong) didn't really glean a lot for me.

Comment: `.slice()` will need to iterate over the elements that it is making a copy of, but not over the entire array.  `.map()` will iterate the entire array.  If you're trying to compare `.slice()` to `.map()` for copying the entire array, then `.slice()` doesn't have to call a callback for every element in the array and could certainly be more optimized.  The implementation is likely complicated because V8 can have some different storage forms for arrays depending upon whether they are sparse or not.

Comment: ^ This. It's unlikely that they reuse same piece of code because such abstraction would be less efficient. This isn't specific to Node, it's V8.